# Exclude column when Exporting table in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, excel, export

Is there any way how can I exclude specific columns when exporting table to excel file, I just want to exclude Firstname and Savings to excel file. Currently I just only export all of my data from my tables but I want to exclude Firstname and Savings column, Is there any expert can help?
[image]

> html

```
<button id='btnExport'>
Export To Excel
</button>
<table id='testExportId'>
  <tr>
    <th >Firstname</th>
    <th >Lastname</th>
    <th >Savings</th>
    <th >wowww</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$150</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Swanson</td>
    <td>$300</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td>Brown</td>
    <td>$250</td>
    <td>$100</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

> javascript

```
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnExport").click(
            function () {
                tableToExcel('testExportId','test','trys');
            }            
        );
})
function getIEVersion()
// Returns the version of Windows Internet Explorer or a -1
// (indicating the use of another browser).
{
    var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
        if (re.exec(ua) != null)
            rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
    }
    return rv;
}
function tableToExcel(table, sheetName, fileName) {
    
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
    {
        return fnExcelReport(table, fileName);
    }

    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
        templateData = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
        base64Conversion = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) },
        formatExcelData = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }

    $("tbody > tr[data-level='0']").show();

    if (!table.nodeType)
        table = document.getElementById(table)

    var ctx = { worksheet: sheetName || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }

    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,' + 
    base64Conversion(formatExcelData(templateData, ctx)));
    element.setAttribute('download', fileName);
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);

    $("tbody > tr[data-level='0']").hide();
}

function fnExcelReport(table, fileName) {
    
    var tab_text = "<table border='2px'>";
    var textRange;

    if (!table.nodeType)
        table = document.getElementById(table)

    $("tbody > tr[data-level='0']").show();
    tab_text =  tab_text + table.innerHTML;

    tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");//remove if u want links in your table
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, ""); // remove if u want images in your table
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // reomves input params

    txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
    txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
    txtArea1.document.close();
    txtArea1.focus();
    sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", false, fileName + ".xls");
    $("tbody > tr[data-level='0']").hide();
    return (sa);
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add class "excludeExport" in column that you want to exclude

```
<button id="btnExport">Export To Excel</button>
<table id="testExportId">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th class="excludeExport">Savings</th>
    <th>wowww</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td class="excludeExport">$100</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td class="excludeExport">$150</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Swanson</td>
    <td class="excludeExport">$300</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td>Brown</td>
    <td class="excludeExport">$250</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and replace $(document).ready to this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnExport").click(function () {
    var tempTable = $("#testExportId").html();

    $("#testExportId .excludeExport").remove();

    tableToExcel("testExportId", "test", "trys");

    $("#testExportId").html(tempTable);
  });
});
```